# Is there any easy way to find all usages of a dataset filed in SSRS desinger?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a dataset with 15 fields used in different expressions of different textboxes. Is there any easy way to see where each of these fields are used? I mean to get a list of all usages?

I'm using Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help ..

In Business Intelligence Development Studio 2008 with the project open.

1. Click menu .. Edit >> Find and Replace >> Find in Files >
2. A dialog window will appear for you to search the string. Type in the string you want to search. You should have "Look In:" default to "Entire Solution". Click Find All button
3. You should be able to see a Find Results window anchored somewhere (on mine it's at the bottom). You will see all the places in your report with the string. Double click on the line will take you to the code where the string is.

Note: Be careful not to enter any values into the code by mistake and save the report form code window as this may break your report.

Sorry not enough points to post pictures.

Comment: Using 'Find in Files' feature will search the XML presentation of the report, which is not the best way possible. but at least it will give a list of appearances of a field.
Originally, I was hoping for a visual way of getting a list of all usages of a filed.